# "Average" of the Median vs "Median" of the Median

Tags: r, distributions, inference, mean, median

I have the following question: **Can similar statistical inferences be made about the median as the mean?**

I will provide context to my question below (using the R programming language).

Suppose there are 10 students : These students were asked to run 100 meters, and their times were recorded (in seconds). The students then repeated this exercise everyday for 10 consecutive days. Their times are recorded below:

```
     student first_run second_run third_run fourth_run fifth_run sixth_run seventh_run eight_run ninth_run tenth_run
1   student1  19.70847   21.79771  16.49083   19.51691  13.97987  14.60733    13.89703  15.24651  20.75679  18.44020
2   student2  11.22369   15.36253  16.90215   20.20724  15.90227  15.14539    13.74945  18.30090  19.55124  17.24132
3   student3  15.93649   17.03599  14.20214   13.17548  14.70327  15.49697    13.08945  19.94142  22.41674  17.37958
4   student4  16.18733   15.13197  14.79481   16.75177  14.51287  17.71816    13.45054  14.25553  19.89091  18.88981
5   student5  18.71084   18.85453  17.15864   19.38880  15.68862  18.39169    15.26428  16.04526  18.92532  16.62409
6   student6  19.75246   12.74605  18.52214   17.92626  14.48501  17.20780    13.10512  12.46502  20.68583  15.87711
7   student7  14.75144   23.82376  18.51366   20.77424  14.22155  16.08186    12.95981  12.67820  20.12166  15.66006
8   student8  17.06516   15.63075  13.72026   15.02068  14.21098  15.99414    14.64818  16.15603  21.74607  17.07382
9   student9  20.27611   12.44592  12.26502   15.13456  14.61552  18.72192    15.11129  17.60746  18.83831  17.55257
10 student10  17.70736   16.21620  14.10861   17.20014  16.59376  19.50027    13.05073  15.80002  18.09781  18.34313
```

From here, we can calculate the mean and median of the run times for each student:

```
library(dplyr)

new_data = my_data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(median_of_student = median(c_across(where(is.numeric))),
         mean_of_student = mean(c_across(where(is.numeric))))

new_data = data.frame(new_data)

     student first_run second_run third_run fourth_run fifth_run sixth_run seventh_run eight_run ninth_run tenth_run median_of_student mean_of_student
1   student1  19.70847   21.79771  16.49083   19.51691  13.97987  14.60733    13.89703  15.24651  20.75679  18.44020          17.46551        17.44611
2   student2  11.22369   15.36253  16.90215   20.20724  15.90227  15.14539    13.74945  18.30090  19.55124  17.24132          16.40221        16.36258
3   student3  15.93649   17.03599  14.20214   13.17548  14.70327  15.49697    13.08945  19.94142  22.41674  17.37958          15.71673        16.28130
4   student4  16.18733   15.13197  14.79481   16.75177  14.51287  17.71816    13.45054  14.25553  19.89091  18.88981          15.65965        16.11303
5   student5  18.71084   18.85453  17.15864   19.38880  15.68862  18.39169    15.26428  16.04526  18.92532  16.62409          17.77517        17.52975
6   student6  19.75246   12.74605  18.52214   17.92626  14.48501  17.20780    13.10512  12.46502  20.68583  15.87711          16.54246        16.30139
7   student7  14.75144   23.82376  18.51366   20.77424  14.22155  16.08186    12.95981  12.67820  20.12166  15.66006          15.87096        16.85975
8   student8  17.06516   15.63075  13.72026   15.02068  14.21098  15.99414    14.64818  16.15603  21.74607  17.07382          15.81245        16.09805
9   student9  20.27611   12.44592  12.26502   15.13456  14.61552  18.72192    15.11129  17.60746  18.83831  17.55257          16.34356        16.26475
10 student10  17.70736   16.21620  14.10861   17.20014  16.59376  19.50027    13.05073  15.80002  18.09781  18.34313          16.89695        16.68318
```

From here, I can evaluate:

- The mean of the mean: `mean(new_data$mean_of_student)` = 16.59
- The mean of the median: `mean(new_data$median_of_student)` = 16.44
- The median of the mean: `median(new_data$mean_of_student)` = 16.33
- The median of the median: `median(new_data$median_of_student)` = 16.37

**My Question:** **In statistics, do we take the "median of the mean" or the "mean of the median"?** (For the matter, I have never heard of the "median of the median" either). **Are these calculations even meaningful?** Or is there only statistical theory that supports taking the "mean of the mean" (e.g. for statistical inference, hypothesis testing, confidence intervals)?

Thanks

**Extra**: **Data Visualizations**

Below, we can see the distributions of the means and medians for all students:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

data<- melt(new_data[,c(12,13)])
ggplot(data,aes(x=value, fill=variable)) + geom_density(alpha=0.25) + ggtitle("Mean vs Medians of Students")
 ggplot(data,aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_boxplot() + ggtitle("Mean vs Median of Students")
```

[image]

And here, we can see the distributions of the run times themselves:

```
data<- melt(new_data[,-c(12,13)])
ggplot(data,aes(x=value, fill=variable)) + geom_density(alpha=0.25) + ggtitle("Distribution of Run Times")
 ggplot(data,aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_boxplot() + ggtitle("Distribution of Run Times")
```

[image]

Comment: You can do what is suitable in your circumstances.  If each subset has the same number of elements as the other subsets, then the *mean of the means* is the mean of the whole set.  You cannot say anything like that for the others

Comment: You could look into [tag:quantile-regression], as the 50% quantile is the median.

Comment: This question, "do we take...," has no definite answer because you haven't specified what your *estimand* is.  That is, what specific quantitative property are you attempting to estimate?